# Mongodb Query based on a column which contains dateTime information

Tags: json, mongodb, datetime, nosql, mongoexport

I have a Mongodb collection with event data. it has a column called dateTime. I want to retrieve & export  all the data that are after specific date.

Example of data in the dateTime column is as follows.

```
2022-11-21T15:16:50.029+08:00,

2022-11-21T15:15:57.950+08:00
```

i tried to retrieve using below commands.

```
mongo --host=127.0.0.1 --username=admin --password="xxxx" --authenticationDatabase=admin --eval 'db.myevents.find({ "dateTime": { "$gte": { "$date": "2005-11-21T09:58:36.141+08:00" } } }).count()'
```

Returns 0. But as you can see there are data like the above examples I have provided.

```
mongoexport --host=127.0.0.1 --username=admin --password="xxxx" --authenticationDatabase=admin --db my_thing  --collection myevents --query '{ "dateTime": { "$gte": { "$date": "2005-11-21T09:58:36.141+08:00" } } }' --out myData.json
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got it working with this locally, `mongoexport --db=testdb  --collection=myevents --query="{ \"dateTime\": { \"$gte\": { \"$date\": \"2005-11-21T09:58:36.141+08:00\" } } }" --out=myData.json --host="127.0.0.1:27017"`. Are you sure the datatype is datetime?

Comment: Try `{ dateTime: { $gte: ISODate("2005-11-21T09:58:36.141+08:00") } }`

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Thanks for giving me a clue. i executed typeof db.event.findOne().dateTime. Out put is String. So i think date is stored as string. Still unable to get export working.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments your datatype is a string, to make it work you will need to convert your date strings to date, in the query. This worked for me, locally, you can do something similar:

```
mongoexport --db=testdb  --collection=myevents --query="{ \"$expr\": { \"$gte\": [{\"$toDate\": \"$datetime\"}, {\"$toDate\": \"2005-11-21T09:58:36.141+08:00\"}]} }
```

In the query, I am using `$expr`, and within it I am converting strings to date objects `$toDate`.